# Retrieve MySQL 8.0 Table Structure From IBD File

Tags: mysql

**TLDR:**
This post only applies to MySQL version 8.0. It's about how to recover a database using the IBD file when you don't have or remember the exact table structure for the tables in your database.

**Request:**
Ever since MySQL 8.0, the IBD file contains the data needed to recreate the exact table structure that's required to recover a database using only the IBD file - they got rid of FPM files. However, a large portion of the data isn't self-explanatory, so does anyone know about any resources that help interpret the data that's produced by the "ibd2sdi" MySQL tool?

**Problem:**
MySQL was working fine, and without changing anything, it stopped working. It won't start, uninstall or reinstall. I've troubleshooted the errors, but I couldn't fix the issue. Instead, I created a new virtual machine, installed MySQL, created a new database, created a new table with the exact same table structure (thankfully I had it saved), transferred the IBD file, and successfully recovered the database. I was able to solve my problem because I had a copy of the exact table structure, but I couldn't find a solution that would work for someone who doesn't have the exact table structure of their table.

**Progress:**
MySQL stopped using FPM files in version 8.0. Instead, the data is stored using a different format inside of the IBD file. The data can be accessed in json format using the "ibd2sdi" tool that comes with mysql. I found a [resource](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/12/07/mysql-8-frm-drop-how-to-recover-table-ddl/) that covers how to retrieve the basic table structure, but not enough to recreate the exact same table which is is required to recover the database. However, I noticed a pattern in the json data that fills in enough of the remaining table structure to recreate basic tables.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The "columns" section in the JSON data contains information about the columns in the table. Each column has a property called, "column_key." This property refers to whether a column is indexed or not. Its property value is either 1, 2, 3, or 4. These values represent "not indexed," "primary key," "unique," and "multiple occurrences," respectively. There are also other properties that are self-explanatory that should allow anyone to recreate the exact table structure for basic tables.